# Find the owner of the wallet

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

I made a transaction to a wrong wallet address.
There is no way you can assign an email to it?
Or any other way I can get my money back?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is by searching the wallet address on Twitter to see in case anyone has shared their address publicly before or not, however the chances are very very slim to find a owner this way. There is no email attached to Solana accounts by default, its blockchain, afterall. If you have sent your funds to a wrong address, then the chances of you finding the owner are close to zero.

To avoid that happening in future, make sure to send a small amount, let's say 0.001 SOL as a test. Mistakes teach us, don't worry too much!